# Avoiding heap space issue- Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I do perform the following steps: (This entire thing is part of one java process)

1. Get the parent list of items from the rest webservice.
2. For each item, we get the child list from DB.
3. For each child list, fetch its details from the rest webservice by passing the child list. The detail returned is per client so the response is a list
4. This details is stored in one **final parent list** containing child details.

**Note**: Step 3 and 4 is a loop.

After the above steps below are performed:

1. The **final parent list** containing the details is saved to the database. For saving have used the spring jdbc template n a fork join pool as the list is huge. DB is Sybase.
2. The **final parent list** is used to created a BCP file.

But the problem is **final parent list** gets too huge which causes heap space issues.

Someone suggested that flush the child detail list each time to DB and BCP file instead of waiting till end and using the **final parent list**. And in parallel load them and save them. I fell this will increase the DB hits.

Kindly suggest ideas.

Comment: Use batches if you want to decrease the number of accesses to the database. But of course, this is all theoretical - we don't know what you use to write to DB, what DB it is, what your data structures look like. So no detailed answer is possible.

Comment: I am using sping jdbc template.. n it's the ArrayList.. DB is Sybase..  but the entire process happens in a single java process..

Comment: what is final parent list for? If the goal is to save it to a file, then save it in parts as soon as next part is available. If it should be processed, then process in step by step etc.